# jquery, close tab menu when click again

Tags: jquery, css

I have tab menu that can close current tab when click again.

And when click the menu, text color change to red(active), but the problem is when click it again, it does not change to blue(default).

How do I change the code ?

check demo here, http://jsfiddle.net/GkGyt/173/

```
<div id="tabs_container">

      <!-- These are the tabs -->
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li>
          <a href="#" rel="#tab_1_contents" class="tab">Option 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="#tab_2_contents" class="tab">Option 2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="tab_contents_container">

        <!-- Tab 1 Contents -->
        <div id="tab_1_contents" class="tab_contents tab_contents_active">Option 1 stuff        </div>

        <!-- Tab 2 Contents -->
        <div id="tab_2_contents" class="tab_contents">Option 2 stuff</div>
        </div>


$('.tab_contents').hide();

  $('.tab').click(function() {
     var target = $(this.rel);          
        $('.tab_contents').not(target).hide();
        target.slideToggle(100);
  $('#tabs_container > .tabs > li.active')
      .removeClass('active');

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');



  $('#tabs_container > .tab_contents_container > div.tab_contents_active')
      .removeClass('tab_contents_active');

  $(this.rel).addClass('tab_contents_active');
 });



a { color:blue}
.tab_contents { border:1px solid #000; }
.active a { color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.tab_contents').hide();
var count = 0; 
$('.tab').click(function() {
    count++; //increment count everytime it is clicked
    var target = $(this.rel);  
     $('.tab_contents').not(target).hide();
     target.slideToggle(100);
    $('#tabs_container > .tabs > li.active')
    .removeClass('active');
    if((count % 2) != 0) { 
         $(this).parent().addClass('active');
     } else { 
         $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
     } 
 $('#tabs_container > .tab_contents_container > div.tab_contents_active')
  .removeClass('tab_contents_active');
 $(this.rel).addClass('tab_contents_active');
});
```

Simple calculation, keep track of the count

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `toggleClass()`, I have an example below to solve your issue.

```js
$('li.tab').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul li.tab a {
    color: blue;
}

ul li.active a {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="tab">
        <a href="#">Button 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a href="#">Button 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```